# php access mssql 2005 database, sqlsrv drivers

Tags: php, sql-server, windows, sql-server-2005

I am attempting to access a mssql 2005 database using Microsoft's supplied sqlsrv drivers.  I have tried every driver version from 3.1 to 2.0, installing a different version of XAMPP with different versions of PHP installed.

- version 3.1 = php version 5.4.7
  error:

> This extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client.
>   Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2012
>   Native Client ODBC driver for x86

- version 3.0 = php version 5.3.1 error:

> This extension requires either the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Native
>   Client (SP1 or later) or the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Native
>   Client ODBC Driver to communicate with SQL Server. Neither of those
>   ODBC Drivers are currently installed. Access the following URL to
>   download the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client ODBC driver
>   for x86:

- version 2.0 = php version 5.2.1 and 5.2.4

> Php drivers are unrecognized and do not appear in phpinfo().

I am under the impression the extension should [support](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098) ALL EDITIONS of SQL Server 2005 and greater...

I installed both the SQL Server 2012 Native Client and the SQL Server 2008 Native Client (SP3).
According to [this](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/138541/EN-US) article I can test the ODBC connectivity to a SQL Server.

Entering odbcping at a command prompt returns:

> 'odbcping' is not recognized as an internal or external command....

I checked the ODBC Data Source Administrator and found the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server is listed in the drivers tab.

[image]

Any assistance as to what I may be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up two things: ODBC and PHP drivers for MS SQL Server 2005.

- If you install SQLDRV 3.X, you dont use ODBC.
- If you use ODBC, then you may need different PHP driver than SQLDRV.

I also struggled few hours with setting up PHP connection to MS SQL Server 2003, 2005, 2008 with Studio Express. I used **pdo_sqldrv** driver installed via SQLDRV drivers provided by Microsoft. Installing PHP drivers was easy part. Once you see **pdo_sqldrv** in phpinfo(), you are done with PHP driver. Difficult is second part - setting up properly MSSQL environment to allow PHP for connection. I did following steps:

- downloaded & installed free MSSQL Studio Express 2005 (or 2008, both work fine)
- installed or upgraded to dotNetFx40Setup.exe
- installed msxml6.msi (I think this was only needed for version 2005)
- installed MSSQL Native Client
- logged into studio and created new user for PHP only with read/write permissions
- enabled pipe and other connection resources
- figured out correct connection string "sqlsrv:server=PCHOME\\SQLEXPRESS;database=eshop"

Then it worked, but definitely it was not easy setup. G'd luck.